# Java Swing button stays pressed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a java button that creates a thread, but the button stays pressed even after the thread finished doing the job.

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Calculus());
        t.start();
    }
}

public class Calculus implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    //do stuf
    }
}
```

Am I implementing Runnable in the wrong way? Or does the thread need something to finish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the way a `JToggleButton` works. Just use a `JButton` for a normal Swing button.